# Slides in GIF format - Would like to convert into 1 PDF file (using PHP)?

Tags: php, image, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have a series of images that are screenshots of PowerPoint slides.  I would like to join these images into 1 PDF file using PHP.

Can anyone direct me to a script or tutorial that does this?

Here is an example of series of images that I wold like to convert into a single PDF document:

- https://flevy.com/images/slideshows/566/0.gif
- https://flevy.com/images/slideshows/566/1.gif
- https://flevy.com/images/slideshows/566/2.gif
- https://flevy.com/images/slideshows/566/3.gif
- https://flevy.com/images/slideshows/566/4.gif

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Image`](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) method can do that for you:

```
require ('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->Image($i.'.gif', 0, 0, 250, 200);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

This will put each slide on a new page. You might want to adjust the image proportions (the last two parameter).